# List of wifi network not showing on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, drivers, 17.10, network-manager, broadcom

I have a dell latitude d620 on which i run both window 7 and ubuntu 17.10. but i discovered that whenever i log on ubuntu, it doesn't always find any network. it always search forever, something which is different when i log on to windows. 
i have gone through many thread, but their answers seems not helping.
i will post the list of codes that i have run below and their result.

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlp12s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:19:d2:49:fc:6f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.13.0-38-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:efdff000-efdfffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:18:8b:a6:60:41
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=5752-v3.19 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:efcf0000-efcfffff
```

I tried

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

But it said

```
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

I tried:

```
iwconfig
```

result

```
wlp12s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp9s0    no wireless extensions.
```

**i tried this**

```
lspci | grep -i -E wireless\|ethernet
```

**and got this**

```
    09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02). 
0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
```

This also:

```
sudo iwlist wlp12s0 s
```

always see some network, but will not display it in the GUI

```
wlp12s0   Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: A4:BA:76:74:97:EA
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                Encryption key:off
                ESSID:"Xender_APd5dc"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000001b34f0d
                Extra: Last beacon: 28ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000D58656E6465725F415064356463
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                IE: Unknown: 200100
                IE: Unknown: 23021300
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A200017FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 7F0104
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180200000C0000
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

pls i need help, i've been on this for weeks.

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

the result is below:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

for the second command

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

The result is as follow:

```
/etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for 
ifup(8), ifdown(8)
 Generated by debian-installer.  

 The loopback interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
```

I also noticed that my computer do connect with the network that i use to set it up during installation whenever the network is available. Its a wireless network from my phone. But it won't even show the name of that network nor other networks. But my phone always tell me when the laptop connect with its hotspot. So i can't use any other WiFi network except one with that very name and password.
**pls i need help**
::,

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I've done that

Comment: Pls anyone here that can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Network manager was the problem, that thing made me suffer for 6 months. I solved this by running the following codes:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd

sudo service network-manager stop

sudo service wicd start
```

Comment: Wicd works better for me.